# How to fix: too short external monitor's resolution after HDMI reconnect until reboot?

Tags: 12.04, display, resolution, hdmi, external-monitor

I am working on a notebook with external monitor via HDMI and experiencing the same problem each day - in one specific case the external monitor's resolution is not set correctly - gets `1600x1200` instead of `1920x1200` and can't be picked from GUI, but the correct max resolution is shown in AMD control Center - yet as an information only.

After a reboot with connected monitor it is okay, but when I reconnect the monitor on a suspended the system - the problem appears.

It is ok as long as I reconnect the monitor on awaken system, but that's poor reason to wake the system up when I want disconnect the monitor and later have appropriate resolution, when I connect it back.

Is there a way to force the system to always set the same resolution for specific display regardless to anything?

---

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 x64
Notebook: HP 655
GPU: Radeon HD 7340 integrated (most likely on CPU but from lspci)
CPU: E2-1800 APU
Drivers: Gallium 0.4 on AMD PALM - xorg alone, no fglrx
Monitor: Samsung SyncMaster 2493HM

Comment: More info, a better chance to get  answers. Could you add more info about your hardware setup. (graphic card, monitor, driver,..)

Comment: I don't know if problem would persist on Ubuntu 14.04 and 1) xorg 2) universal fglrx 3) compiled fglrx. Easier for now to not use external monitor since I'am about to change notebook anyway...